# Why does JavaScript Math.log(1.001) return the wrong value?

Tags: javascript, math

JavaScript returns .0009995003330834232.

Every other way of calculating returns 0.000434077479319.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It returns the [natural logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm), i.e. the logarithm to base `e = 2.71828...`, instead of the logarithm to base 10.

```
log_e(1.001) = 0.00099950033308342321
log_10(1.001) = 0.0004340774793185929
```