# Math.log returns incorrect value

Tags: javascript, math, logarithm

I found a bug in calculating logarithm using Math.log function in JavaScript. For example, consider a number (say 0.1), actual `log value of 0.1 to the base 10 is -1`.

But when I use `Math.log` function in javascript it returns `-2.302585`. Clearly, this is wrong, So, should I write my own function to calculate logarithm or is there any other methods available in JavaScript to calculate logarithm manually ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript Math.log(1.001) return the wrong value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040611/why-does-javascript-math-log1-001-return-the-wrong-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log:

> The Math.log() function returns the **natural** logarithm (**base e**) of a number.

Perhaps you want `Math.log10`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10, but not supported in IE.

Basic math says you can convert a natural logarithm to a base 10 logarithm by dividing by 2.303. This constant is defined as `Math.LN10`, so:

```
function log(x) {
    return Math.log(x) / Math.LN10;
}
```

or more generally:

```
function log(x, base) {
    return Math.log(x) / Math.log(base);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, there should be a generic method to calculate logarithms for all bases in JS, right?

Comment: Doesn't need to be, just multiply by the appropriate conversion factor.

Comment: I checked your answer and edited your code to generically calculate logarithm for any base not only 10. I guess this is correct.